# How to capture a screenshot when not actually logged into the machine during running Selenium tests with Jenkins on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, selenium, jenkins, screenshot

We have a CI environment with Jenkins running a test suite of Selenium Tests in a Windows (XP and/or Windows 7) VM.  If I am not physically logged into the VM running these tests via RDP, all I see are black (blank) PNGs. I've tried all of the 'capture' methods available (both Base 64 encoded and file based) for multiple Selenium RC 2ish releases (e.g 2.0b2, 2.0rc3, 2.0.0, 2.1.0) and I get the same results for everything I've tried.  Is anyone else running Selenium in a Windows CI deployment and able to capture screens?  Or better stated, can anyone shed light on how I can capture screens in Windows, using the Selenium API without having to be physically on the box"?

Comment: What are you using for making Test Suite? Ant? or Maven?

Comment: Does the screen capture happen only when the tests fail. How can I get screenshots of all the pages/clicks that an automated test is performing using a given build system (Gradle/Maven/ANT) and using Selenium as test framework behind Xvfb :xx virtual frame buffer?

Answer (score 3):

If you are not logged onto the box, or you either closed or minimized the RDP connection, there is no desktop, and screen captures will be blank.

What you need to do is use a VNC server/viewer, so that the machine/vm in question has a visible desktop session.

Comment: +1 You should also disable the lock screen functionality of windows.

Comment: Better yet, run the Selenium server as a service instead of as a user.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, running as a service may not work. There are tradeoffs depending on what kind of account you have the service run as. If the Se service runs as a local system account, you can check the option to allow the service to interact with the desktop. However, if your Se tests/framework require access to your network and you set up the Se service to run as a domain user, then 'allow service to interact with desktop' option is not available.

Comment: FWIW, one of the first things I tried was running SS as a service (interacting with the desktop, Windows 7 - SS ver: 2.0b2, 2rcs, 2.0 - although havent't tried 2.1.0), and it produced the same results (e.g. blank pngs)...  as I'm assuming whether you run this as a service or not, it still doesn't have a "visual context" to capture.

Answer (score 2):

We are also doing something very similar. We have a windows VM setup which is running Hudson and Selenium Grid.
When our test cases fail we capture a screenshot of the browser so we get more detail of why a test case failed.
We are using the #captureEntirePageScreenshotToString method

Comment: Ok, can you share with me more about your environment?  (e.g. flavor of Windoze, version of Selenium server, how Selenium server is started (by Hudson via ant, as a service, other?)  We aren't running Grid so the visual context it's capturing is where you deployed your RCs.  I'd be interested in hearing about how many RCs, and what those clients are running as well.... thx!

Comment: We are running Selenium Grid 1.0.8 on a WINTEL 2003 box. We have a grid running with four Selenium servers which are started through command line using ant commands.
The user which started the Grid is always kept logged in so there is always a Desktop environment for screenshots to be captured in.
Our tests are setup in TestNG

Comment: I was using captureScreenshot and getting the blank screen. Switching to captureEntirePageScreenshot fixed the issue. So I think if you refine this solution to just "use captureEntirePageScreenshot" it will be the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

We're doing it, and it works for us.  We're using JetBrains' TeamCity instead of Jenkins, running on Windows Server 2003.  We run the Selenium RC server as a Windows service, using the [Java Service Launcher](http://jslwin.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: ok, what version of RC are you using?  So, this box runs a "headless" browser session when it's capturing these images?  For what browser?  A little more info would be much appreciated, thx!!

Comment: We're using Selenium RC 1.0.1, but Selenium 2.x ought to work just the same, since there hasn't been much real change in RC for a long time.

This works for Firefox, and for IE if you install the SnapsIE extension (https://github.com/nirvdrum/SnapsIE) that Selenium requires.  The session isn't really "headless", because Windows always thinks it has a head, but we're using EC2-based build agents, so there sure ain't no screen :-)

Comment: I tried this with multiple configurations and it didn't work for Selenium2.x. I tried with both the System account with "interact with desktop" on, and my own domain account. Can you post the ini file you used for JSL?